# ruby oracle-enhanced stuck connection after sleep

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord, sinatra

Thank you for your attention. We got a bit stuck with stuck connections with after some idle period and would appreciate any help or things to try.

We're using v1.4.1 of activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter with ojdbc6.jar in a Sinatra app on jruby 1.7.2. My controller calls a helper class method and returns a json string. The helper class method simply queries an Oracle database for data. The code looks like this:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  get '/customer/:id_number' do |id_number|
    MyHelper.customer(id_number).to_json
  end
end

class MyHelper
  @dbconfig = YAML.load_file("../config/database.yml")
  @dbenv = @dbconfig["#{settings.environment}"]

  puts "establish_connection"
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(@dbenv)

  def self.customer(id_number)
    begin
      query = <<-SQL
        SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cust_id = '#{id_number}'
      SQL
      puts 1
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query)
      puts 2
    rescue => e
      puts 3
      puts e.message
    ensure
      puts 4
      ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
      puts 5
    end
   end
end
```

We have a shell script that hits the controller 50 times, sleeps for 2 hours and repeats. We can see one call to establish_connection at the beginning (expected). What we don't expect is that right after the sleep, the first connection to the database always gets stuck. What we'd see in the log is just "1". After 15 minutes, the client times out and makes another call to the controller. This second call seems to have the effect of "waking up" the connection pool, in that it always resumes thread 1 and so we'd see "2", "4" and "5". Concurrently, we'd also see thread 2's log messages: "1", "2", "4" and "5". We know because the actual code prints Thread.current.object_id as part of the message.

We tried adding ActiveRecord::Base.connection.verify! right before exec_query but that only shifts the stuck call to the verify line.

Did we use the adapter correctly? Is there something else we can try?

Answer (score 0):

I'd implemented a solution using event machine and oracle adapter, I yes, the error was there, the only way to "fix" this issue was forcing my app to reconnect to oracle, so here is my example

```
unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?
  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
  rescue => e
    EchoServer.log e
  end
end
```

So, before every Active Record connection, I ask if the connection is still alive, if not, I try to reconnect manually, at the time, it is working, but, this is not the most optimal solution, but .... hopefully it will work

PD:
there are some issues related to this error, here a couple of them:

https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/420

[Does reaper work with oracle-enhanced adapter (OCI) to reap out idle connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490822/does-reaper-work-with-oracle-enhanced-adapter-oci-to-reap-out-idle-connections/22174640#22174640)