# Does reaper work with oracle-enhanced adapter (OCI) to reap out idle connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to play with connection pooling with activerecord in Ruby. I am using Oracle-enhanced adapter and setting the following properties in database.yml:

```
reaping_frequency: 30
dead_connection_timeout: 20
```

I don't see my idle connections getting reaped.

I am using Rails3. I think reaper is available in Rails4.

Comment: The "answer" you posted is [not a valid answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Stack Overflow has a question-and-answer format, not a discussion thread format. "Answer" means you're actually providing an answer to the question; it's not the same as "Reply" in a discussion forum. Please read the [About](http://www.stackoverflow.com/about) page to get a better understanding of the site's format.
 To add information to your question, click the gray "edit" link under the question.

Comment: I've added the information from the "answer" to your question. In the future, please use edits to update your questions.

Answer (score 0):

As you say Reaper is only available in Rails 4. However, even with rails 4, oracle-enhanced adapter still does not work with reaper. There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/420) with oracle-enhanced adapter to add support for it for reaper.